# Javascript Text Rotate

Tags: javascript, php

Hello guys it's been bugging me all night. I've been trying to get together a word rotate feature that decreases in speed and then eventually stops. Think of it like a word roulette. So i have the words stored in an array and it looks over the words and displays them. Now, i need to decelerate the speed and slowly make it stop and a random lettter, how would i go about this ?

```
<?php 



    $json=file_get_contents('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.18.1/data/en_US/champion.json');
$champions = json_decode($json);
?>

<?php

$championsArray = array();
foreach($champions->data as $champion){
  $championsArray[] = $champion->id;
}
shuffle($championsArray);
$speed = 1000;
$count = count($championsArray);
var_dump($championsArray);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="demo1 no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>jQuery Super Simple Text Rotator Demo 1: Default Settings</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Rotating text is a very simple idea where you can add more content to a text area without consuming much space by rotating an individual word with a collection of others" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery text rotator, css text rotator, rotate text, inline text rotator" />
    <meta name="author" content="Author for Onextrapixel" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../file/favicon.gif"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />

    <!-- Edit Below -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.wordrotator.css">
      <script src="jquery.wordrotator.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="demo1">
    <div class="container">

<p><span id="myWords"></span></p>

      <div class="main">

         <a href="#" onclick="erm()">Go!</a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- Container -->

<script type="text/javascript">


function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}


   function erm() {
    var cont = $("#myWords");

    $(function () {
        $("#myWords").wordsrotator({
          randomize: true,  
          stopOnHover: true,       //stop animation on hover
          words:   ['Heimerdinger','Ezreal','Skarner','Nunu','Kennen','Lulu','Morgana','Sejuani','Draven','Nocturne','KogMaw','Jinx','Khazix','Cassiopeia','Fiora','Maokai','Zac','Quinn','Vladimir','RekSai','LeeSin','TwistedFate','MissFortune','Shaco','Vayne','Sivir','Urgot','Nautilus','Annie','Fizz','Janna','Irelia','Karthus','Trundle','Jax','Graves','Leona','Rengar','Amumu','Malzahar','TahmKench','MasterYi','Twitch','Rumble','Nidalee','Shyvana','Veigar','Singed','Riven','Leblanc','Katarina','Azir','Viktor','Poppy','Ahri','Yorick','Aatrox','Brand','Tryndamere','DrMundo','Hecarim','Braum','Nasus','Pantheon','Elise','Velkoz','Swain','Darius','Kayle','Thresh','Nami','Ekko','Alistar','Galio','Warwick','Orianna','Sona','Lux','Ryze','Jayce','Kassadin','Volibear','Blitzcrank','Gangplank','Karma','XinZhao','Ziggs','Malphite','Tristana','Soraka','Anivia','Xerath','Renekton','Shen','Lissandra','Ashe','Mordekaiser','Talon','Zilean','JarvanIV','Rammus','Yasuo','Vi','Bard','Sion','Udyr','MonkeyKing','Akali','Diana','Varus','Kalista','Evelynn','Teemo','Gnar','Garen','Taric','FiddleSticks','Chogath','Zed','Lucian','Caitlyn','Corki','Zyra','Syndra','Gragas','Olaf']


        });

    });
    eventFire(document.getElementById('myWords'), 'click');

  }

</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Are you wanting to use CSS animation and just set start and end, or do you want to control the rotation in realtime?

Comment: Honestly, i'm not fussy between using CSS or JS animation. I just want a list of words to rotate quickly then decrease in speed until it stops. I thought the best way to do this would have been JS but i'm not great with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify a bit the `wordrotator` plugin so that it allows to change the speed on each rotate.

You'll have to tweak the animation and the speed increment, but this should give you some ideas:

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.wordsrotator = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            autoLoop: true,
            randomize: false,
            stopOnHover: false,
            changeOnClick: false,
            words: null,
            animationIn: "flipInY",
            animationOut: "flipOutY",
            speed: 40,
            onRotate: function () {},//you add these 2 methods to allow the effetct
            stopRotate: function () {}

        };
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        var listItem
        var array_bak = [];
        var stopped = false;

        settings.stopRotate = function () {//you call this one to stop rotate 
            stopped = true;
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            var el = $(this)
            var cont = $("#" + el.attr("id"));
            var array = [];

            //if array is not empty
            if ((settings.words) || (settings.words instanceof Array)) {
                array = $.extend(true, [], settings.words);

                //In random order, need a copy of array
                if (settings.randomize) array_bak = $.extend(true, [], array);


                listItem = 0
                //if randomize pick a random value for the list item
                if (settings.randomize) listItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)

                //init value into container
                cont.html(array[listItem]);


                // animation option
                var rotate = function () {


                    cont.html("<span class='wordsrotator_wordOut'><span>" + array[listItem] + "</span></span>");

                    if (settings.randomize) {
                        //remove printed element from array
                        array.splice(listItem, 1);
                        //refill the array from his copy, if empty
                        if (array.length == 0) array = $.extend(true, [], array_bak);
                        //generate new random number
                        listItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
                    } else {
                        //if reached the last element of the array, reset the index 
                        if (array.length == listItem + 1) listItem = -1;
                        //move to the next element
                        listItem++;
                    }

                    $("<span class='wordsrotator_wordIn'>" + array[listItem] + "</span>").appendTo(cont);
                    cont.wrapInner("<span class='wordsrotator_words' />");
                    cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordOut").addClass("animated " + settings.animationOut);
                    cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordIn").addClass("animated " + settings.animationIn);

                    settings.onRotate();//this callback will allow to change the speed

                    if (settings.autoLoop && !stopped) {
                        //using timeout instead of interval will allow to change the speed
                        t = setTimeout(function () {
                            rotate()
                        }, settings.speed, function () {
                            rotate()
                        });
                        if (settings.stopOnHover) {
                            cont.hover(function () {
                                window.clearTimeout(t)
                            }, function () {
                                t = setTimeout(rotate, settings.speed, rotate);

                            });
                        };
                    }
                };


                t = setTimeout(function () {
                    rotate()
                }, settings.speed, function () {
                    rotate()
                })
                cont.on("click", function () {
                    if (settings.changeOnClick) {
                        rotate();
                        return false;
                    };
                });



            };

        });
    }

}(jQuery));

function eventFire(el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}


function erm() {
    var cont = $("#myWords");

    $(function () {
        $("#myWords").wordsrotator({
            animationIn: "fadeOutIn", //css class for entrace animation
            animationOut: "fadeOutDown", //css class for exit animation
            randomize: true,
            stopOnHover: true, //stop animation on hover
            words: ['Heimerdinger', 'Ezreal', 'Skarner', 'Nunu', 'Kennen', 'Lulu', 'Morgana', 'Sejuani', 'Draven', 'Nocturne', 'KogMaw', 'Jinx', 'Khazix', 'Cassiopeia', 'Fiora', 'Maokai', 'Zac', 'Quinn', 'Vladimir', 'RekSai', 'LeeSin', 'TwistedFate', 'MissFortune', 'Shaco', 'Vayne', 'Sivir', 'Urgot', 'Nautilus', 'Annie', 'Fizz', 'Janna', 'Irelia', 'Karthus', 'Trundle', 'Jax', 'Graves', 'Leona', 'Rengar', 'Amumu', 'Malzahar', 'TahmKench', 'MasterYi', 'Twitch', 'Rumble', 'Nidalee', 'Shyvana', 'Veigar', 'Singed', 'Riven', 'Leblanc', 'Katarina', 'Azir', 'Viktor', 'Poppy', 'Ahri', 'Yorick', 'Aatrox', 'Brand', 'Tryndamere', 'DrMundo', 'Hecarim', 'Braum', 'Nasus', 'Pantheon', 'Elise', 'Velkoz', 'Swain', 'Darius', 'Kayle', 'Thresh', 'Nami', 'Ekko', 'Alistar', 'Galio', 'Warwick', 'Orianna', 'Sona', 'Lux', 'Ryze', 'Jayce', 'Kassadin', 'Volibear', 'Blitzcrank', 'Gangplank', 'Karma', 'XinZhao', 'Ziggs', 'Malphite', 'Tristana', 'Soraka', 'Anivia', 'Xerath', 'Renekton', 'Shen', 'Lissandra', 'Ashe', 'Mordekaiser', 'Talon', 'Zilean', 'JarvanIV', 'Rammus', 'Yasuo', 'Vi', 'Bard', 'Sion', 'Udyr', 'MonkeyKing', 'Akali', 'Diana', 'Varus', 'Kalista', 'Evelynn', 'Teemo', 'Gnar', 'Garen', 'Taric', 'FiddleSticks', 'Chogath', 'Zed', 'Lucian', 'Caitlyn', 'Corki', 'Zyra', 'Syndra', 'Gragas', 'Olaf'],
            onRotate: function () {
              //on each rotate you make the timeout longer, until it's slow enough
                if (this.speed < 600) {
                    this.speed += 20;
                } else {
                    this.stopRotate();
                }
            }


        });

    });
    eventFire(document.getElementById('myWords'), 'click');

}
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";
 .wordsrotator_words {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: width 100ms;
    -moz-transition: width 100ms;
    -o-transition: width 100ms;
    transition: width 100ms;
}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut, .wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordIn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 50ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-duration: 50ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-duration: 50ms;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut span {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordIn {
    opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
.fadeInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOutDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}
.fadeOutDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
    animation-name: fadeOutDown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p><span id="myWords"></span>
    </p>
    <div class="main"> <a href="#" onclick="erm()">Go!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i did some tweaking and now it works perfectly.